# What is causing "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type error"?

Tags: c, pointers, incompatibletypeerror

I'm trying to experiment here with pointer arithmetic, but I get this warning. I am unable to understand where is this going wrong.

The code is written to play with pointer arithmetic since my basics are weak.

```
    printf("To Check ptrs \t");
    int var[3]={10,20,30};
    int *ptr,i;
    ptr=var;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
       printf("Address is %d \t", ptr);
       printf("Value is %d \t", *ptr);
       ptr++;
    }
    ptr=(int*)&var;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
       printf("Address is %d \t", &ptr[i]);
       printf("Value is %d \t", ptr[i]);
    }
```

```
ptr_arith.c:14:5: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  ptr=&var;
     ^
```

I got the desired output, though. Also, when I use

```
ptr=(int*) &var;
```

,it doesn't give me any error.
So if someone can tell me what's causing it to be "incompatible", I'll be thankful.

Comment: Note also - `&ptr[i])` is type `void` (it's just the address of the ith element). Trying to print as `"%d"` is a type mismatch resulting in *Undefined Behavior*. Enable compiler warnings, `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS, and don't accept code until it compiles without warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple.

You should arrays decays to pointers in the following way:

`int arr[10];`

`arr` is of type `int *`

`&arr[0]` - is of type int *

`&arr` is of type pointer to the array of 10 integers.

In your code you shuld use

`ptr = var` or `ptr = &var[0]` as `var` and `&var[0]` have the same type as pointer `ptr`.

`&var` different type, thus the warning.

Comment: You might add that `var` is *array of* `int [3]`, therefore `&var` has the type *pointer-to-array-of* `int [3]`?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store a address of a array using pointer use type conversion before assigning address of a array

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer? How does it address the OPs question?

Comment: Adding casts to silence the compiler is not a good idea.